# Как исправить ошибки в верстке?

Tags: jquery, html, вёрстка, javascript, css

Всем привет!

Как исправить ошибки в верстке?

1. Футер почему лезет на карту?
2. Высота body не становится равным 100%.
3. Нельзя нажать на поиск, как будто его нет.

Все, буду благодарен, если подскажете!
http://test.webjay.ru/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не забывать, что при верстке используешь фреймворк. Добавь карте class="grid_12". Не забудь убрать margin, top и position у карты.

Answer (score 1):

В класс karta добавь `clear: both;`.